# I recently returned after a while and found my user profile changed

Tags: support, user-accounts

I finally got back to perusing Mi Yodeya after a "vacation"... when I looked at my profile, it looks like my Facebook page picture replaced the colored splotch, and my full name and email was on there.  What happened? Did some sort of automatic data transfer between FB and MY occur?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me likely that two user accounts of yours were merged, one for which you chose your Facebook picture as the avatar and your real name and e-mail address, and one for which you chose the default splotch (or perhaps some other splotch) and no real name or e-mail address. For whatever reason (I'm sure there is one if this is true, but don't know what it is), the software chose to use the data from the former.

Just so you know, your full name and e-mail address are visible only to you, site moderators, and Stack Exchange employees.

Comment: Do you have the priv'ges necessary to check if that's what happened?  I am CERTAIN I only did one profile here... I think way back when I might've "logged in using FB" that might've somehow caused the data share... I definitely didn't figure out how to load the FB photo as my avatar.....weird...

Comment: It was definitely a surprise!

Comment: @Gary, I can see two accounts were merged, but not what data were associated with either.

Comment: This was very likely an automatic merge by the system after seeing verified email addresses match between accounts, we do this as folks sometimes forget what they used to sign in and end up creating a new account, so we try to put them together when we detect it. Apologies for it startling you, wasn't our intention :)